# How to send a variable from javascript to View in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using Django

I have a template that contain a form and the users can generate a div i called it "teamcard" as much as they need. after that they will send the form with all the "teamcard" information to view.
The problem is that I can't send the count of the generated form from javascript to the view, because I need a for loop in view to save all the "TeamCard" in database.
please inform me how to send the counter from javascript to view
here are my codes:

```js
var counter = 0;

function member_card()
{
    counter += 1;
    document.getElementById('name').setAttribute('name', 'name'+counter);
    document.getElementById('job').setAttribute('name', 'job'+counter);
    document.getElementById('explain').setAttribute('name', 'explain'+counter);
    document.getElementById('linkedin').setAttribute('name', 'linkedin'+counter);
    document.getElementById('gendermale').setAttribute('name', 'gender'+counter);
    document.getElementById('genderfemale').setAttribute('name', 'gender'+counter);

    
    var newFields = document.getElementById('teamform').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name;
  if (theName)
   newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('formhere');
 insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
    
}

window.onload = member_card;

function count() {
    return counter;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="{% url 'landingpages:registerfinal' s_id.id %}"
                          method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div name="membercard" class="row">
                            <div id="teamform" class="col-md-4" style="display: none">

                                <!--
                                <div name="imageholder" class="row tm-image-holder">
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
                                        <img id="myimg" style="height: 200px;text-align: center;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="photoinput" type="file" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary inout-margin
                                 mybut">
                                -->

                                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="add-input input-margin"
                                       placeholder="Name, Mohammad, ... *">
                                <input id="job" name="job" type="text" class="add-input input-margin"
                                       placeholder="Job, Developer, Designer, ... *">
                                <input id="linkedin" name="linkedin" type="text" class="add-input input-margin"
                                       placeholder="linkedin.com/Me">
                                <textarea id="explain" name="explain" class="add-textarea input-margin" rows="4"
                                          placeholder="Explain this member in 2 to 4 lines *"></textarea>

                                <input type="radio" id="gendermale" name="gender" value="male"> Male
                                <input type="radio" id="genderfemale" name="gender" value="female"> Female

                            </div>
                            <span id="formhere"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div name="addform" class="row input-field">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: left">
                                <a onclick="member_card()">+ Add Team Member</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="submit" name="membersubmit" value="Next Step" class="btn btn-primary mybtn3">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: A way to do it could be, process the values in JavaScript and then make a ajax call to the view and send the data. For example, use JQuery.post() http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: If you have multiple forms, you should have a normal button (not a submit button per form) and create a click event in JQuery to process all the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: Remember that you can't have DOM elements with same Ids, so when you generate the second form each fields should have their unique id.

HTML

```
<form id="form1">
  <input id="name1" type="text" value="hola1"/> 
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input id="name2" type="text" value="hola2"/> 
</form>

<form id="form3">
  <input id="name3" type="text" value="hola3"/> 
</form>

<button id="mySubmitButton">submit</button>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){

  $('#mySubmitButton').on('click', function(){

    // for each form in your html you can process then and save the information in an object 
    var form_data = {}

    $("form").each(function() {
       var input_id = $(this).find('input').attr('id');
         var input_value = $(this).find('input').val();

       form_data[input_id] = input_value;
        });

        console.log(form_data);

    $.post( "your django view url", {data: form_data}, function( data ) {
      // maybe show a success or fail message accordantly
    });

  });


});
```